# CRUD operations to couchbase from AWS Lambda using couchbase sdk for node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, couchbase, nosql

I need to run CRUD operations on my bucket (database) in couchbase which is deployed ec2 instance. And the code which I have is running on aws lambda. However, when I try to test this code on lambda by passing details in the body I get the error as : **"errorMessage": "/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /var/task/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node)"**. This error is because in my function I require an npm module called "couchbase" which is used for executing CRUD operations on my couchbase bucket.

So can you guys help me as to what might be the problem here? Is the file missing on nodejs environment running on lambda or do I need to implement in a different way so as to get it working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to rephrase and make you question clearer.

Comment: Looks like an install issue, can you make sure you have libstdc++6 installed and configured correctly?

Comment: was able to solve the above issue by locally compiling node_modules required for the function with same nodejs version on which lambda runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by locally compiling node_modules with the same nodejs version (v0.10.36) which lambda uses and uploading the zip file to lambda.